# why does not a placeholder inside a method in insert sql work?

Tags: sql, prepared-statement, parameter-passing, dynamicquery

In my case,

```
INSERT INTO xmltable (id, xml_content) 
VALUES (?,XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><mail><from>abc</from><to>xyz</to></mail>' PRESERVE WHITESPACE))
```

is working fine, but

```
INSERT INTO xmltable (id, xml_content) 
VALUES (?,XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT ? PRESERVE WHITESPACE))
```

is not.

Comment: What does the calling code look like?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something e

Comment: Currently I am using Derby but in future I will use DB2

Comment: My problem is I have to use format  XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT  ' ? ' PRESERVE WHITESPACE) where ? will be replaced by a string having xml content. I tried putting xml string inside single quotes (' ') that did not work